# Simple Telegram client that read new channel messages that I'm Subscribed?

Tags: c++, telegram, telegram-api

I need to read all new messages of one specific channel that I'm in (not as an admin but I,m Subscribed). I need to do this by C++. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 Server.
I Install TDlib by the following Commands :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install make git zlib1g-dev libssl-dev gperf php cmake g++
git clone https://github.com/tdlib/td.git
cd td
git checkout v1.6.0
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
export CXXFLAGS=""
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local ..
cmake --build . --target prepare_cross_compiling
cd ..
php SplitSource.php
cd build
cmake --build . --target install
cd ..
php SplitSource.php --undo
cd ..
ls -l /usr/local
```

can anybody give me a simple C++ example and command to compile that to run over console and get new incoming messages from specific channel? i need to be all login and API client info () be in the code. any help will be really appreciated.